# Change drupal admin password for 100 sites using drush

Tags: drush, users

I've a requirement to change admin password for drupal 7 sites which are over 100 and i would like to do it with drush. I know one method of doing it is updating user table with a shell script listing databases in a queue, but i want to achieve this with drush. Would be great if anyone can put me in some reference if they have any idea.

### Cheers,

Swaroop.

Comment: Check this @Swaroop : http://randyfay.com/content/resetting-drupal-passwords-drupal-7-drush-or-without

Answer (score 1):

**Recover password with Drush**

Drush offers several ways of recovering the administrator's password.
Generate login-link

Drush can generate a one-time login link.

```
drush uli
```

Reset password

```
drush upwd --password="givememypasswordback" admin
```

(where "admin" is the user name)

For more info visit [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/44164#drush)

Comment: Challenge is we need to reset for more than 100 websites. Does alias help?

Comment: `for site in alias1 alias2 alias3 ; do drush "@$site" upwd --password="doyoureallywantthesamepasswordeverywhere" admin ; done`

Comment: `drush @alias1,@alias2,@alias3 upwd --password="doyoureallywantthesamepasswordeverywhere" admin`